# Increase the size of Django-Ckeditor's codesnippet

Tags: python-3.x, django, ckeditor

I've implemented the django-ckeditor library, which I use to write my post, but the problem is that if you want to add a code snippet to your blog, there is no way you can increase the font size inside the code snippet. I'm looking for someone who has an idea on how to increase the font size and padding of the code snippet. Thanks

And this is the configurations for the django-ckeditor

```
CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = "uploads/"
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
'default': {
    'toolbar': 'all',
    'skin': 'moono',
    'fontSize': '18px',
    # 'codeSnippet_customization': '/static/css/codesnippets.css',
    # 'codeSnippet_theme': 'monokai_sublime',
    'extraPlugins': ', '.join(
        [
            'codesnippet',
            'dialog',
            'widget',
        ]
    ),
}},
```

[image: How the code snippet look like]